# Looking for a way to use V2Ray in Flutter and Swift - Need Assistance

Tags: android, ios, flutter, proxy, vpn

I couldn't find a way to use V2Ray in Flutter. The libv2ray package is not actively working. I haven't had a chance to look into the Android platform yet, but I also couldn't find a way to use it effectively in Swift. Can anyone help me with this issue?